# Onscreen keyboard cut-off (spacebar, ctrl, alt off-screen)

Tags: raspberrypi, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

Running a freshly installed and updated Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop for Raspberry Pi (64-bit) with the 7 inch touch screen, the onscreen keyboard appears to be rendering too low such that the Ctrl, Alt, and spacebar keys are off the bottom of the screen (the tops of the keys are barely visible):

[image: Screenshot of onscreen keyboard with bottom cut off]

There is a lot of unused space above the number row.

**How do I get the onscreen keyboard to render correctly?**  Or is there a way to change the size or resolution of the onscreen keyboard?

Comment: Try with Onboard: `sudo apt install onboard`. Let us hope that it is available and works well not only for PC computers but also for RPi.

Comment: Onboard works (and I can see the entire keyboard!); however, it doesn't appear at login, which makes it difficult to enter a password with, say, spaces in it.  Is there a way to use Onboard as Gnome's default onscreen keyboard?  I've done a little hunting around but nothing obvious has turned up, short of switching to xubuntu/lubuntu or maybe using a different desktop manager.

Comment: I'm sorry, but have not found a way to use Onboard at Gnome log in. I suggest that you simply change the password (use only characters that are available on the default onscreen keyboard as it is in your case).